# Python process group efficiently

Tags: python-3.x

I have an ldap query that I am using to populate a database. I cant process more than 1000 at a time. Currently I am looping through each user and building a string using a counter. This seems inefficient . Is there a way to parse the 1000 at a time without using a counter? This is what I currently have.

```
users=conn.extend.standard.paged_search(ldapqeuery,paged_size=1000,generator=true)
for user in users:
    if(counter<999)
       appendToQuery(user)
    else:
        counter=0
        executeSQL()

executeSQL() # this one is to do any remaining
```

Comment: regardless of your question, your code is bug-a-ly skipping each 1000th user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with using an auxiliar "counter" variable as you do - and it is part of Python "success formula" to allow one to just type-in what he is thinking about to solve a problem.

It can be made "prettier" by the use of the built-in `enumerate`, which can provide an index along with each item in a `for` iteration, though:

```
users=conn.extend.standard.paged_search(ldapqeuery,paged_size=1000,generator=true)
for counter, user in enumerate(users): 
    appendToQuery(user)
    if counter % 1000 == 0 and counter > 0:
        executeSQL()

if counter % 1000:
     executeSQL()
```